# What are possible reasons that cmd stop writing to a file with redirection?

Tags: file, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

This is on win7.

I got a batch script that executes a C++ program and take all of its output to the file with ">".

The program takes input from servers and display everything. We need all these information so we log all these outputs down to a file. But after a short while, we see that the program stops writing to the file and just stop there while the program continues running.

The file size is also at 0 byte (OS doesn't update until file is closed?) But we can see the content of the file with notepad++, but it does not seem to update any longer.

There are about 250,000 lines long and we see that our data simply got cut off in the end. For example, suppose you should have a table of data that lists out 123 567 436 975, we only see 123 567 43. The whole line isn't even finished in the end.

There are a lot of things to write down and there are lots of network transmission. Does the program simply give up outputting when there are too much data? Is there a way around this?

Comment: How do you generate output from c++ program?

Comment: Redirected output is buffered, makes it a lot more efficient.  Now it matters how the program stops.  If you kill it then you won't get the data that's still in the buffer.

Comment: How often does the buffer got transferred? Because I tried waiting for 10 minutes and using notepad++, I see nothing new is written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable buffering. `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`.

Anyway, in new versions of windows, when a file is being created and data is being written (the clasic `>file` scenario), the grow of the file is not always visible.

In this case, `dir` command shows a 0 bytes file, or stops to show increasing values.

Try to read the file with `type file >nul` and then `dir file`. This "should" refresh the file size information. But it is not needed. The file is growing, just not showing it.